# How to setup build pipeline in Azure dev ops

Tags: build, azure-devops, release, pipeline

I am trying to setup my build and release pipelines in Azure dev ops to publish my webforms application to a file system on a VM on my companies network. Currently this is accomplished through Visual Studio by going to Build > Publish ...

I have a build pipeline set up previously I was using to catch build issues. But now I want to actually publish the builds from the cloud automatically when the master branch is updated.

I have an agent installed on a local VM and I can get Azure dev ops to run on this agent but I have some confusion as to what to do next. I've tried playing around with the Build Solution Task parameters, MSBuild task parameters and so on but it doesn't actually publish it.

The farthest I've gotten is to publish the build to a build folder on the agent but this only contains the solution and associated files, not the built output that would be published to the file system location.

I'm trying to understand how to actually publish the solution once it's been built and placed on the agent.

It also doesn't help that I can't find very good resources on the build variables that all of the default tasks are using.

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad.  Maybe try walking through the [guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=tfs-2018-2) on configuring the pipelines.  You are probably missing the step to [publish your build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops).

Comment: It sounds like your not actually building the solution, what tasks do you have in your build pipeline? If you have a look at the MSBuild or VSBuild task that could build the solution for starters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops

Comment: Build is only work for compile. Which target do you want to publish to? IIS? Or any other? If you want to deploy the compiled output to the local vm, you need to get a connection with VM first and configure a stage to finish deployed in the release pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Build pipeline is responsible for building your software and publishing built artifacts (build output) inside Azure DevOps for release pipelines. Release pipeline is responsible for deploying your website into test/production environment.

First you need to ensure that your build is publishing artifacts (output of build) inside azure devops for the release pipeline. This is achieved by using **publish artifacts task**.

[image]

Path to publish is the directory that contains your build output (files that are copied into VM). You can use relative paths with artifactsstagingdirectory. You can leave drop into artifact name, because that is just the name for zip file, also use Azure Pipelines in artifact publish location.

Now your build is creating artifacts for **release pipelines**. You can verify this by looking one of the builds in build history. Top right corner should contain artifacts:
[image]

If it's not there, then your build is not publishing artifacts correctly. Check build log for more details!

Now if you have azure devops agent running inside VM, the deployment is an easy task.

1. Stop IIS website with IIS Web App Manage task
2. Copy artifacts into desired folder (for example c:\wwwroot) with Copy files task.
3. Start IIS website with IIS Web App Manage task

Make use you have linked build into release pipeline. When you are creating the release pipeline first time. It will ask to set this setting.
[image]